# FMDB crashed in inserting record after adding one new column to existing table

Tags: ios, swift, fmdb

I have added one new column to my existing table using below code.

```
let alterTable = "ALTER TABLE tble_abc ADD COLUMN TestColumn INTEGER default 0"
if FMInst.database!.executeUpdate(alterTable, withArgumentsIn: nil)
{
    print("new column added")

}
FMInst.database!.close()
```

Now while performing the insert operation it always get crashed at

```
- (BOOL)executeUpdate:(NSString*)sql error:(NSError**)outErr withArgumentsInArray:(NSArray*)arrayArgs orVAList:(va_list)args {

 some code in between


while (idx < queryCount) {

        if (arrayArgs) {

             obj = [arrayArgs objectAtIndex:idx];
// Crashing point
        }
        else {
            obj = va_arg(args, id);
        }


}
```

showing idx value 8 and query count 9 with an error message “Fatal error: Array index out of range”

Previously there was 8 values now there are 9 after the alteration of table but it shows 8 values only.

Can any body help me out in this.

Comment: Print your table columns and check are their 9 columns?

Comment: I have checked in DBBrowser after altering the table it shows 9 column.

Comment: Check in your code..